# image is not displaying in imageview of new pop window in android

Tags: android

i am very new. trying to make a project which will show image and text in listview. up to this, it is ok. but when i click the image new window appeared without image. Please help me.
code is below:

```html
1. package com.imagemysql;

2. import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
3. import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
4. import java.io.BufferedReader;
5. import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
6. import java.io.Closeable;
7. import java.io.IOException;
8. import java.io.InputStream;
9. import java.io.InputStreamReader;
10. import java.io.OutputStream;
11. import java.net.URL;
12. import java.util.ArrayList;
13. import java.util.HashMap;


14. import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
15. import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
16. import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
17. import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
18. import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
19. import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
20. import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
21. import org.json.JSONArray;
22. import org.json.JSONException;
23. import org.json.JSONObject;


24. import android.os.Bundle;
25. import android.os.StrictMode;
26. import android.util.Log;
27. import android.view.LayoutInflater;
28. import android.view.Menu;
29. import android.view.View;
30. import android.view.ViewGroup;
31. import android.widget.AdapterView;
32. import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
33. import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
34. import android.widget.ImageView;
35. import android.widget.ListView;
36. import android.widget.TextView;
37. import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
38. import android.app.Activity;
39. import android.app.AlertDialog;
40. import android.content.Context;
41. import android.content.DialogInterface;
42. import android.graphics.Bitmap;
43. import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;


44. public class MainActivity extends Activity {

a. public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS = 0;
b. public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_FULL_PHOTO_PROGRESS = 1;
c. // private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

d. ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArrList;


45. @SuppressLint("NewApi")
46. @Override
47. public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
48. super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
49. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

50. // Permission StrictMode
51. if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
52. StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
53. StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
54. }

55. // listView1
56. final ListView lstView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

57. /** JSON from URL
• [
• {"ImageID":"1","ImageDesc":"My Sea View 1","ImagePath":"http://www.thaicreate.com/android/pic_a.png"},
• {"ImageID":"2","ImageDesc":"My Sea View 2","ImagePath":"http://www.thaicreate.com/android/pic_b.png"},
• {"ImageID":"3","ImageDesc":"My Sea View 3","ImagePath":"http://www.thaicreate.com/android/pic_c.png"},
• {"ImageID":"4","ImageDesc":"My Sea View 4","ImagePath":"http://www.thaicreate.com/android/pic_d.png"}
• ]
58. */



59. String url = "http://10.0.2.2/getimage1.php";

60. try {
61. JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

62. final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
63. HashMap<String, String> map;

64. for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
65. JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
66. map = new HashMap<String, String>();
67. map.put("ImageID", c.getString("id"));
68. map.put("ImageDesc", c.getString("codigo"));
69. map.put("ImagePath", c.getString("descripcion"));
70. MyArrList.add(map);
71. }


72. lstView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MyArrList));

73. final AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
74. final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

75. // OnClick


76. lstView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
77. public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
78. int position, long id) {

a. View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
79. ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);




80. try
81. {
82. image.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(MyArrList.get(position).get("Imagepath")));
83. } catch (Exception e){
84. //if get error
85. image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
86. }
87. imageDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
88. imageDialog.setTitle("View : " + MyArrList.get(position).get("ImageDesc"));
89. imageDialog.setView(layout);
90. imageDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

91. public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
92. dialog.dismiss();
93. }

94. });

95. imageDialog.create();
96. imageDialog.show();

97. }
98. });

99. ///} catch (private Collection getJSONUrl(String url1) {
a. // TODO Auto-generated method stub
100. //// return null;
101. ////}

102. ////(JSONException e) {
103. // TODO Auto-generated catch block
104. ////e.printStackTrace();

105. } catch(JSONException e){
106. e.printStackTrace();


107. }

108. }

109. public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
110. {
111. private Context context;
112. private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

113. public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list)
114. {
115. // TODO Auto-generated method stub
116. context = c;
117. MyArr = list;
118. }

119. public int getCount() {
120. // TODO Auto-generated method stub
121. return MyArr.size();
122. }

123. public Object getItem(int position) {
124. // TODO Auto-generated method stub
125. return position;
126. }

127. public long getItemId(int position) {
128. // TODO Auto-generated method stub
129. return position;
130. }
131. public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
132. // TODO Auto-generated method stub

133. LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

134. if (convertView == null) {
135. convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);
136. }

137. // ColImage
138. ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
139. imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 70;
140. imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 70;
141. imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
142. try
143. {
144. imageView.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(MyArr.get(position).get("ImagePath")));
145. } catch (Exception e) {
146. // When Error
147. imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
148. }

149. // ColPosition
150. TextView txtPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgID);
151. txtPosition.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
152. txtPosition.setText("ID : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageID"));

153. // ColPicname
154. TextView txtPicName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgDesc);
155. txtPicName.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
156. txtPicName.setText("Desc : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageDesc"));



157. return convertView;

158. }

159. }

160. /*** Get JSON Code from URL ***/
161. public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
162. StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
163. HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
164. HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
165. try {
166. HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
167. StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
168. int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
169. if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
170. HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
171. InputStream content = entity.getContent();
172. BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
173. String line;
174. while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
175. str.append(line);
176. }
177. } else {
178. Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
179. }
180. } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
181. e.printStackTrace();
182. } catch (IOException e) {
183. e.printStackTrace();
184. }
185. return str.toString();
186. }



187. /***** Get Image Resource from URL (Start) *****/
188. private static final String TAG = "ERROR";
189. private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 40 * 1024;
190. public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
191. Bitmap bitmap = null;
192. InputStream in = null;
193. BufferedOutputStream out = null;

194. try {
195. in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

196. final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
197. out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
198. copy(in, out);
199. out.flush();

200. final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
201. BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
202. //options.inSampleSize = 1;

203. bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
204. } catch (IOException e) {
205. Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
206. } finally {
207. closeStream(in);
208. closeStream(out);
209. }

210. return bitmap;
211. }

212. private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
213. if (stream != null) {
214. try {
215. stream.close();
216. } catch (IOException e) {
217. android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Could not close stream", e);
218. }
219. }
220. }

221. private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
222. byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
223. int read;
224. while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
225. out.write(b, 0, read);
226. }
227. }
228. /***** Get Image Resource from URL (End) *****/


229. @Override
230. public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
231. getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
232. return true;
233. }

234. }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part of the code isn't working.  Also, add more logging, and then post your logs after reproducing the issue.

Comment: Your wall of code accompanied by the abysmal formatting will likely mean no help.

Comment: Learn to indent. Code is meant to be *readable* by humans, and incidentally is ran by computers.

Comment: is this part for display image after click? 75. // OnClick


76. lstView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
77. public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
78. int position, long id) {

a. View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
79. ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);